# I am having an issue with Nagios Instalation

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I am having an issue with the Nagios Installation. After Make Install I am getting below error. I would realy appraciate it if you can help me with this.

I am beginner in Linux.

cd ./base && make install
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/Downloads/nagios-4.4.4/base'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 775 -o nagios -g newnagios--with-command-group=newnagcmd -d /usr/local/nagios/bin
/usr/bin/install: invalid group 'newnagios--with-command-group=newnagcmd'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:176: install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/Downloads/nagios-4.4.4/base'
make: *** [Makefile:276: install] Error 2

Comment: Start by using an appropriate distro. Kali is an advanced distro not designed for what you are doing or your level of knowledge.

Comment: It is a trivial typo, before all the `--`s you need a space. You inserted a command snippet from the internet without understanding it. I don't discourage so strongly to not use Kali, but you will need to learn a lot. Another bad practice what you committed: *you should not compile anything as root*.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for answers and help. this distro is only Temp, no access to the internet. I agree that I should not use root user but OS was  installed and removed yesterday from VM.  Also, I have figured out it and I was able to install nagios and addons on kali. Anyway thanks for help and we can close this topic.